# java bukkit - error in the string message.replace("&", "§")

Tags: java, file, replace, message, bukkit

the console send a error message in line 154

```
//files
  //mensagens.yml
    ServerTag: '&0[&cServer&0] '
    SugVipAnotada: '&aSua sugestao foi recebida e anotada! e por ser vip sera lida primeiro!'


//Code:
  //in onEnable:
                File file1 = new File(getDataFolder(), "mensagens.yml");
        if (!file1.exists()) {
            try{
                saveResource("mensagens.yml", false);
            }
            catch (Exception localException) {}
            }

  //in onCommand:

        try {
            config.load(configL);
        } catch (IOException | InvalidConfigurationException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
/*ERROR*/sender.sendMessage(config.getString("ServerTag").replace("&", "§") + config.getString("SugVipAnotada").replace("&", "§"));
```

i don't have idea of why the error has ocurred

observation: the plugin is translated for portuguese why i am of brazil :) (is for complete more lines of text)

Comment: Please show the full error and stacktrace.

Comment: Which is the 154 line??

Answer (score 1):

In the future, please provide as must detail as possible. Chances are that a NullPointerException is being thrown by `getString()` because it cannot find the configuration item `ServerTag` or `SugVipAnotada`.

You should either check if the result is null first, or provide a default value. For example.

```
String serverTag = config.getString("ServerTag");
if ( serverTag == null ) {
    // Bark some error or throw exception if value is expected
}
```

or

```
String serverTag = config.getString("SeverTag", "some def value");
```

In regards to color conversion (`&` to `§`): while `replace()` will indeed replace every `&` with `§` that is not what you want. There are cases when `&` is part of the message such as **Welcome to Bait & Tackle**. It is better to use `replaceAll()` and leverage regex to only convert what needs to be converted.

```
msg.replaceAll( "(?i)&([0-9A-FK-OR])", "§$1" )
```

If you want to strip any color annotation to get raw text, you can use

```
msg.replaceAll( "(?i)(&|§)[0-9A-FK-OR]", "" )
```

I hope this helps and gets you going. Best of luck with the rest of the plugin translation.